# How I can filter lens inside resolveCodeLens?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, codelens

I am trying to split `CodeLensProvider` implementation in two parts. First part is implementation of `provideCodeLenses` which returns array of unresolved `CodeLens`. And the second part is implementation of `resolveCodeLens`.

So I want to ignore some kind of `CodeLens` don't match some conditions inside `resolveCodeLens` because `provideCodeLenses` **should return as fast as possible**. Is it possible to do?

Right now I just got `<<MISSING COMMAND>>` for unresolved `CodeLens`.

#### An Example

```js
class Provider implements CodeLensProvider {
  provideCodeLenses() {
    return [lensA, lensB, lensC];
  }

  resolveCodeLens(lens) {
    return executeCommand('vscode.someCommand')
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.isTrue) {
          return lens.resolve();
        } else {
          // ignore `lens`
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. According to the [answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62137) on the VSCode repository, this is not possible to do. :(

Comment: However, according to the offical sample (github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/…) and doc, for performance reasons the creation of a code lens and resolving should be done to two stages, but since the resolveCodeLens seems to only process one codelens, it confuses me if I have multiple codelens.